# Python Code is able to retrieve the Header only, but does not get any information afterwards.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Image of html code --> [image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.cfpc.ca/en/members-list').text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', id='memberlist-table')

header = []
rows = []
j = 0

for i, row in enumerate(table.findAll('tr')):
    if i == 0:
        header = [el.text.strip() for el in row.findAll('th')]
        with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            thewriter = writer(f)
            thewriter.writerow(header)
    else:
        rows.append([el.text.strip() for el in row.findAll('td')])
        with open('test1.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
            thewriter = writer(f)
            info = [rows[j],rows[j+1],rows[j+2],rows[j+3]]
            thewriter.writerow(info)
        j = j+4
```

I inputted this code, and everything worked as it was supposed to until it got passed the header, then the code ends as if there is no information in any rows after the header.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the data is loaded and rendered dynamically via `JavaScript` what is not support by `requests`. Try to find the API the data comes from or use `selenium` or somthing similar to mimic browser behaviour - Please be gentle to the endpoints and may use `time` for some delay.

###### Example using API

```
import requests, time

data = []
page_number = 442
while True:
    result = requests.get(f'https://www.cfpc.ca/ajax/memberlist/members.ashx?PageNumber={page_number}&PageSize=100').json().get('responseStatus').get('memberList')
    if len(result) > 0:
        data.extend(result)
        page_number = page_number + 1
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        break
data
```

---

Writing the list of dicts to CSV:

```
with open('members.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, data[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

---

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*